# why Data Annotation with model-binder in asp.net MVC5 not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-mvc-5

i can't understand why model binder not validate data. My code is working fine without model binder. The action i tried to invoke is Enter. So, the url is like this. (localhost:51017/Customer/Enter). My code is given below.

> Customer Controller.cs

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    // GET: Customer
    public ActionResult Load()
    {
        Customer obj = new Customer()
        {
            CustomerCode = "1001",
            CustomerName = "Rezwan"
        };
        return View("Customer", obj);
    }
    public ActionResult Enter()
    {
        return View("EnterCustomer");
    }

    public ActionResult Submit([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomerBinder))] Customer obj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("Customer", obj);
        else
            return View("EnterCustomer");      
    }
}
```

> EnterCustomer.cshtml

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>EnterCustomer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <form action="Submit" method="post">
            Customer Name - <input name="txtCustomerName" type="text" />
            Customer Code - <input name="txtCustomerCode" type="text" />
            <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="submit" />
         </form>
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Customer.cs

```
 public class Customer
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Z]{3,3}[0-9]{4,4}$")]
    public string  CustomerCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

> CustomerBinder.cs

```
 public class CustomerBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        HttpContextBase objContext = controllerContext.HttpContext;
        string CustCode = objContext.Request.Form["txtCustomerCode"];
        string CustName = objContext.Request.Form["txtCustomerName"];

        Customer obj = new Customer()
        {
            CustomerCode = CustCode,
            CustomerName = CustName
        };

        return obj;

    }
}
```

> Customer.cshtml

```html
@model HelloWorld.Models.Customer

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        Name - @Model.CustomerName <br/>
        Code - @Model.CustomerCode
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out. I'm new in asp.net language.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `CustomerBinder.BindModel`, is the code being hit?

Comment: Did you enabled Unobtrusive Client Validation?

Comment: You say your trying to invoke the controller action enter, but your form in EnterCustomer.cshtml maps to the Submit action

Comment: Submit action because i need to validate the inputs from form. and here is the customer class object. @Fran

Comment: see my answer.  you are doing a ton of work that mvc will do for you.  you need to read up on mvc conventions.

Comment: @DiskJunky yes, when i put a breakpoint in BinderModel. Its being hit. But still, not validate the input

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need to create a custom modelbinder here.  You are also going against a lot of the mvc framework convention.  You usually see an action pair like Create (Get) and Create (Post) with a view that is also name Create.cshtml

So using the scaffolding framework in mvc you can generate everything you need from your Customer model class.

Generated view (Create.cshtml):

```
@model Scratch.Mvc.Models.Customer

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>View</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Customer</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

controller action created in CustomerController

```
    // GET: Customer/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Customer/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(customer);
        }

        //do work
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

So the post controller action takes the Customer object and uses the default modelbinder to bind the html form's fields with the object. This works because EditorFor will generate the correct html form field names that will automatically bind to the same named property on the Customer class.

The ModelState check in the POST action then returns the same view with the validation information included which is then bound using the ValidationMessageFor helper method.

It also redirects back to an index page (not defined here) to conform with the PRG pattern.